# Android save bmp image

Tags: android, bmp

I'm trying to save a captured .bmp file to sdcard.
Here is a fragment of code which is responsible for this:

```
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(root + "/mFolder");

    if (!mFolder.exists()) 
    {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    String strF = mFolder.getAbsolutePath();
    File mSubFolder = new File(strF + "/MyApp-SubFolder");

    if (!mSubFolder.exists()) 
    {
        mSubFolder.mkdir();
    }
    String s = "myfile.png";

    File f = new File(mSubFolder.getAbsolutePath(),s);
    String strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try 
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,70, fos);

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.d("asd", "yeah!");
    //  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But there is an error:

> images are invalid and its size are 0kb

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: String s = "myfile.png"; ? and you said the file is .bmp

Comment: try this  File storagePath = new File(
     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp-SubFolder/");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private boolean SaveToSD() {

        String imageName = null;

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        boolean imageSaved = false;

        if (sourceBitmap != null && !sourceBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            File storagePath = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/iGridu/");

            if (!storagePath.exists()) {
                storagePath.mkdirs();
            }

            int count = storagePath.list().length;

            Log.i("SaveToSD count", "" + count);

            imageName = String.valueOf(count + 1) + "_igridu";

            FileOutputStream out = null;
            File imageFile = new File(storagePath, String.format("%s.jpg",
                    imageName));
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                imageSaved = sourceBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
                        90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SaveToSD ", "Unable to write the image to gallery" + e);

            }

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
            values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, imageName);
            values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            values.put("_data", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

            getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        }

        return imageSaved;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your bitmaps are not complete before writing it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i've added it, but it doesnt change anything.