# Get the path of image generated by zxing

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am generating the QR code image from the information based on user by using zxing encode intent. Now i want the path of recently generated image with the image name.Is there any solution to get path of generated image.The name of generated image is also random is there any way to give the custom name to image.

Comment: you can save that image with Current time in Sd Card and retrieve easily from it

Answer (score 1):

zxing lib contains CaptureActivity.java and this class has below mentioned function:

```
private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode)
```

inside this function you will get the image as Bitmap format (Bitmap barcode). so you can make  another function to save this image. here is one link where you will get: how to save image from Bitmatp:
[Android save image from Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834680/android-save-bmp-image)
hope this will help to solve your problem. let us know if it works :) happy coding :)

Comment: i tried the QRGen library and having complete control on the naming and sorting the images for further processing. it worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to control the name. You will always find them in /sdcard/BarcodeScanner/Barcodes though and might identify the latest one by sorting by timestamp.

Comment: i tried the QRGen library and having complete control on the naming and sorting the images for further processing. it worked pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the QRGen library and having complete control on the naming and sorting the images for further processing. it worked pretty well for me. By using QRGen i can control the size as well as name for generated image.